# drive management object, convert MediaType (numerical value) to something more meaningful

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am using the following code to retrieve information about my local drive:

```
ManagementObject c_drive = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
        c_drive.Get();
driveinfo_lbl.Text = "Type: " + c_drive["Mediatype"].ToString();
```

What I am curious about is "MediaType" - how do you convert that to something more meaningful than the number that is returned.  I know you could do it with a struct, but I can't find where the listing is for each value?

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173%28VS.85%29.aspx), which defines the values for the MEDIA_TYPE enumeration used by `Win32_LogicalDisk`.

Comment: Yeah, combined with a small array pretty much sorted that all out, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Managed Object Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132) code, the MediaType is a string.  So I dont think you can get more out of it than that unless you parse it yourself.

Comment: c_drive["Mediatype"] returns a value of 12, I want to know if it is a removable media, logical drive etc. not a numerical value!